# Submit form data to an action as a typed viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I want to submit the data inside a form without a submit button,instead a simple div that has a click event,and all this data should be received by the controller's action as a strongly typed view model.
for example I have the following html

```
<form method="POST"  id="frm" name="frm">
<input type="text" name="Texting"/>
<select name="Car">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 
<input type="checkbox" name="IsChecked" checked="checked"/>

</form>
```

@PageResources.btnSearch

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAction() {
    $.post("DoAction",JSON.stringify($("#frm").serialize()), function(data) {
    });

  }
```

also the controller's action is looking like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoAction(TestViewModel model)
    {

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and the view model

```
  public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Texting;
    public string Car;
    public bool IsChecked;
}
```

when the action is called,the problem is that the model do not have values even i entered something in the controls
what is wrong?why mvc doesn't interpret my data as a viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

In you Jquery Doaction() function . Prepare the viewmodel as follows.

```
var model={
         Texting:$('#IdForInputText').val(),
         Car:$('#IDforSelectList').val(),
         IsChecked:$('#IDForCheckBox').is(':checked'),
}
```

or

```
 var model={
             Texting:$('input[name="Texting"]').val();
             Car:$('select[name="Car"] option:selected').val(),
             IsChecked:$('input[name="IsChecked"]').is(':checked');
    }
```

then use

```
 JSON.stringify(model)
```

Hope it helps .Leave comment if not understood

Comment: the problem is that i do not know the ids of the controls,they are generated whit name of the field+Guid,my team leaders decision.so  i cannot put there something like Texting:$("#Texting_12df3_23232_ert56_34343"),val() it's not looking good. instead i still have that form that encapsulate a bunch of EditorFor(model.Texting),etc so i need some way to interpret that form as a ViewModel when it's passed to the Controller's action

Comment: Many ways are there to retrieve html element through jquery not just by id See the updated answer

Comment: from what i see,the only solution is to create the model from client-side?

Comment: Dear there might be other ways to do it, But I have told you the way which I feel more easy and suitable

Comment: client-side?but the ideea of the guid,is to have unique id's.By using input[name="IsChecked"] i might select more than one control and put it in a single variable,which is not good.i need to take that form as a whole,and parse it right on the server,as the specific ViewModel.how can i do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3887/ check this link , I am sure this will solve your problem